# loop not iterating through entire array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The `foreach` loop below is supposed to grab each value of `Sort` and append it to `$cartesian[]`. When I execute the code, it only uses `salesrank` and `titlerank`.

When I run the main loop without `foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible)` the result is as expected.

When I add `foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible)` It only adds `salesrank` and `titlerank`.

What did I do wrong?

```
$allOptions = array(

    "Sort"  => array(
                        "SportingGoods"         => array("-price", "inverseprice", "launch-date", "price", "pricerank", "relevance-fs-rank", "relevancerank", "reviewrank_authority", "sale-flag", "salesrank"),
                        "Tools"                 => array("-price", "-titlerank", "pmrank", "price", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "Appliances"            => array("-price", "pmrank", "price", "relevancerank", "reviewrank", "reviewrank_authority", "salesrank"),
                        "Electronics"           => array("-price", "pmrank", "price", "reviewrank", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "MusicalInstruments"    => array("-launch-date", "-price", "pmrank", "price", "sale-flag", "salesrank"),
                        "PetSupplies"           => array("-price", "-titlerank", "price", "relevance", "relevancerank", "reviewrank", "reviewrank_authority", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "OutdoorLiving"         => array("-price", "-titlerank", "price", "psrank", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "Industrial"            => array("-price", "-titlerank", "pmrank", "price", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "Automotive"            => array("-price", "-titlerank", "price", "relevancerank", "salesrank", "titlerank"),
                        "HomeGarden"            => array("-price", "-titlerank", "price", "salesrank", "titlerank")
```

.

```
    $finalOptions = $allOptions;
    unset($finalOptions['BrowseNode']);
    unset($finalOptions['Sort']);
    $cartesian_product = cartesian($finalOptions);


    foreach($cartesian_product as $cartesian){
        //add each browse node as is corresponds to the SearchIndex
        foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
            $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = $possible;

            //add each sort option as it corresponds to the SearchIndex
            foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
                $cartesian['Sort'] = $possible;

            }
        }

        $this->itemSearch($cartesian);
            sleep(1);
    }
```

Comment: I'd really love to know why this got downvoted.

Comment: I updated the answer immediately after I posted it, it doesn't generate an array for `$cartesian['BrowseNode']` any more.

Comment: I think it was downvoted because answering the question requires just basic knowledge of PHP (and programming in general) and you didn't put much effort on solving it.

Comment: @axiac unless I'm missing something, it does output an array.

Comment: @axiac This site is for asking questions. Maybe I didn't explain my problem clearly. Maybe assumptions were made. I don't know. However, telling me I lack basic knowledge of PHP and programming is simply uncalled for and wrong. The problem ended up being a very minor issue (see my answer below). I appreciate that you tried to help, but if you thought I didn't put much effort into solving it, you shouldn't have posted an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting, not appending. You need to use `[]` to push an element onto an array.

```
foreach($cartesian_product as $cartesian){
    $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = array();
    $cartesian['Sort'] = array();
    //add each browse node as is corresponds to the SearchIndex
    foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
        $cartesian['BrowseNode'][] = $possible;

        //add each sort option as it corresponds to the SearchIndex
        foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
            $cartesian['Sort'][] = $possible;

        }
    }

    $this->itemSearch($cartesian);
        sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my case, there is no need to store the values, I'll just run `itemSearch()` and be done with it.

Comment: It's not saving the values, because `$cartesian` gets reinitialized each time through the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this piece of code (I removed the part that is irrelevant for the discussion):

```
foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
    $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = $possible;
    ...
 }
```

Of course it doesn't remember all the values of the array. You store them again and again in a single place. Each iteration overwrites the value set by the previous iteration, only the last value is kept after the loop completes.

The same happens on the inner loop:

```
foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
    $cartesian['Sort'] = $possible;
}
```

*Btw, There is no reason to put this loop inside the other loop. It does not depend on any value that changes on the loop over `$allOptions['BrowseNode']`. Even more, because both loops use the same variable `$possible` as iterator, in some contexts unexpected situations can happen.*

#### A possible solution

It is not clear from the question what is the expected outcome. Assuming you want to store the entire array (f.e. `$allOptions['Sort']['Tools']` in `$cartesian['Sort']` then you just assign the entire array at once:

```
foreach ($cartesian_product as $cartesian) {
    // Extract common expression into a variable;
    // this speeds the code up and makes it more readable
    $index = $cartesian['SearchIndex'];

    // Add each browse node as is corresponds to the SearchIndex
    $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = $allOptions['BrowseNode'][$index];

    // Add each sort option as it corresponds to the SearchIndex
    $cartesian['Sort'] = $allOptions['Sort'][$index];


    $this->itemSearch($cartesian);
    sleep(1);
}
```

The code above replaces the values of `$cartesian['BrowseNode']` and `$cartesian['Sort']` with the values extracted from `$allOptions`. If `$cartesian` already contains values on the aforementioned positions and those values must be preserved (and the new values from `$allOptions` added to them) then use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of the assignments:

```
 ...
    // Add each sort option as it corresponds to the SearchIndex
    $cartesian['Sort'] = array_unique(array_merge(
        $cartesian['Sort'], $allOptions['Sort'][$index]
    ));
 ...
```

Use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on the merged array to remove the duplicates (options that already existed in `$cartesian['Sort']` and were also added from `$allOptions['Sort'][$index]`), if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I was calling my function in the wrong place. The correct way was:

```
 foreach($cartesian_product as $cartesian){
        //add each browse node as is corresponds to the SearchIndex
        foreach($allOptions['BrowseNode'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
            $cartesian['BrowseNode'] = $possible;

            //add each sort option as it corresponds to the SearchIndex
            foreach($allOptions['Sort'][$cartesian['SearchIndex']] as $possible){
                $cartesian['Sort'] = $possible;
                $this->itemSearch($cartesian);
                sleep(1);

             }
          }

       }
```

This gives me each possible combination of the data set.